# Sending multiple Images to Web server

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, afnetworking

I am working in an app, where i need to send 3 images to a Web Server. I don't know the perfect method that works fast and efficient.

I have 3 `UIImageView` that capture image data from camera or photo album. Below,I am using `AFNetworking` to send 1 image to Web Server.

```
NSString *imgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Default" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgPath]);

NSData *imagVIewData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView1.image,90);
if (imagVIewData) {    
  AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com/xxx.php]];

NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest =  [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:Nil parameters:Nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

  [formData appendPartWithFileData:imagVIewData name:@"file_upload" fileName:@"123.jpg" mimeType:@"images/jpeg"];
  AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:myRequest];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes",totalBytesWritten,totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
       }];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"upload complete");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",operation.responseString);

}];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
[queue addOperation:operation];
}

}
```

i need someone advice to send 3 different images from 3 UIImageViews. Is it possible with this program or do i need to work through different methods?

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majority of the code you have can actually be kept. Why not try putting all the JPEG representations of the images into an array

```
NSArray *myArrayOfImages = @[Image1,Image2,Image3]
NSArray *myArrayOfNames = @[strings..]
NSArray *myArrayOfFileNames = @[strings..]
```

Then within the constructing body with block parameter put something like this..

```
for(int i=0; i < myArrayOfImages.length; i++){    
  NSData *temp = [myArrayOfImages objectAtIndex:i];    
  NSString *tempFile = [myArrayOfNames objectAtIndex:i]    
  NSString *tempFile = [myArrayOfFileNames objectAtIndex:i]    
  [formData appendPartWithFileData:temp name:tempName fileName:tempFile mimeType:@"images/jpeg"];    
}
```

you could also use a dictionary or whatever data structure you want, point is you just loop over and append within the constructing block.

Comment: thanks a lot Micheal, i will try today and i will let you know my output!

Comment: no problem! I actually barely figured it out a few days ago myself haha!